# fail to build jmeter using gradlew, exception "Self-suppression not permitted"

Tags: gradle, jmeter

New to gradle. According to JMeter, it can be built entirely using Gradle. The basic command is:

`./gradlew build`

However, when I try to build jmeter-rel-v5.4, it reports following error:

> ## ./gradlew build checksum-dependency elapsed time: 30118ms, configurations processed: 4
>
> ```
> SHA-512 computation time: 2ms (goes in parallel, it might exceed wall-clock time), files processed: 1, processed: 0MiB, skipped: 63MiB
> PGP signature resolution time: 27ms (wall-clock), resolution requests: 3, signatures resolved: 42
> PGP key resolution time: 30010ms (wall-clock), resolution requests: 3, download time: 210005ms (goes in parallel, it might
> ```
>
> exceed wall-clock time), keys downloaded: 12
> PGP signature verification time: 0ms (goes in parallel, it might exceed wall-clock time), files processed: 0, processed: 0MiB,
> skipped: 0MiB
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'.
>
> > Self-suppression not permitted
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 32s

I also run it again with "--scan" and upload logs online for diagnosis.
https://scans.gradle.com/s/6dln6uvdiykec

I've set the proxy in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` like:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=my-proxy
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=my-proxy
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you ask your question in [JMeter Users mailing list](https://jmeter.apache.org/mail2.html) or even reach to to a "special" person who introduced Gradle for building JMeter as the process fails somewhere [here](https://github.com/vlsi/vlsi-release-plugins/blob/master/plugins/checksum-dependency-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/github/vlsi/gradle/checksum/pgp/KeyDownloader.kt#L72)?

---

Try amending your command as:

```
./gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=my-proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080-Dhttps.proxyHost=my-proxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 build
```

as I don't know whether `gradel` is a typo or you do believe the configuration should go there.

Moreover `gradlew` indicates that you're using a [Gradle Wrapper](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-wrapper) so most probably the proxy configuration should go to `gradle-wrapper.properties`, also there is [`gradle.properties` file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4/gradle.properties) in the project root where you can set your proxy configuration as well

And last but not the least, according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so it may be worth considering using [`rel/v5.4.1`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/releases/tag/rel%2Fv5.4.1)  tag (or whatever is matching the [latest stable JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi))

Comment: Thanks, ```gradel``` is a typo in the post, I actually modified```~/.gradle/gradle.properties``` as well as the one in project root.  All those measures including -Dhttp.proxyPort etc. in command line, none of them works for me. It makes me think not a proxy configuration issue.

Comment: It seems there is some problem with checksum for ```org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin```. Add ```-PchecksumIgnore``` to ./gradlew build can skip this step. More discussion in https://github.com/vlsi/vlsi-release-plugins/issues/24.