# IDEA Gradle build Jmeter5.4.3 "A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'. > Self-suppression not permitted"

Tags: java, gradle, jmeter

一 、Use IDEA Import
1  apache-jmeter-5.4.3_src.zip
2  Gradle 7.4.1
2  IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)
3  The IDEA of new - >

-> Projects from existing sources

-> Import project -> Import project from external model ->Gradle

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'.
```

> Self-suppression not permitted

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted

二  ./gradlew runGui --info

```
E:\Gitworkspace\apache-jmeter-5.4.3 ❯ ./gradlew runGui --info
```

Downloading key 2c7b12f2a511e325 for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2@jar.asc (attempt 2 of 40, 162.213.33.9, https://keyserver.ubuntu.com)
Downloading key 6449005f96bc97a3 for de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.0.2@jar.asc (attempt 2 of 40, 162.213.33.8, https://keyserver.ubuntu.com)
Downloading key bcf4173966770193 for org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0@jar.asc (attempt 3 of 40, 37.218.245.50, hkp://keys.openpgp.org)
checksum-dependency elapsed time: 136495ms, configurations processed: 4
SHA-512 computation time: 1ms (goes in parallel, it might exceed wall-clock time), files processed: 1, processed: 0MiB, skipped: 63MiB
PGP signature resolution time: 43174ms (wall-clock), resolution requests: 3, signatures resolved: 42
PGP key resolution time: 30004ms (wall-clock), resolution requests: 3, download time: 210006ms (goes in parallel, it might exceed wall-clock time), keys downloaded: 12
PGP signature verification time: 0ms (goes in parallel, it might exceed wall-clock time), files processed: 0, processed: 0MiB, skipped: 0MiB
Saving updated checksum.xml as E:\Gitworkspace\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\buildSrc\build\checksum\checksum.xml
checksum-dependency elapsed time: 0ms, configurations processed: 0 (add -PchecksumTimingsPrint to print detailed timings)
Saving updated checksum.xml as E:\Gitworkspace\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\build\checksum\checksum.xml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'.

> Self-suppression not permitted

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 13s

三、./gradlew clean

```
E:\Gitworkspace\apache-jmeter-5.4.3 ❯ ./gradlew clean
```

checksum-dependency elapsed time: 30080ms, configurations processed: 4
SHA-512 computation time: 0ms (goes in parallel, it might exceed wall-clock time), files processed: 1, processed: 0MiB, skipped: 63MiB
PGP signature resolution time: 14ms (wall-clock), resolution requests: 3, signatures resolved: 42
PGP key resolution time: 30006ms (wall-clock), resolution requests: 3, download time: 240016ms (goes in parallel, it might exceed wall-clock time), keys downloaded: 11
PGP signature verification time: 27ms (goes in parallel, it might exceed wall-clock time), files processed: 1, processed: 0MiB, skipped: 0MiB

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'.

> Self-suppression not permitted

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s

Answer (score 1):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100485/fail-to-build-jmeter-using-gradlew-exception-self-suppression-not-permitted。](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100485/fail-to-build-jmeter-using-gradlew-exception-self-suppression-not-permitted%E3%80%82)

I refer to this sentence in the link above  “Add -PchecksumIgnore to ./gradlew build can skip this step”

I will try use this  “./gradlew build -PchecksumIgnore --info”

OH，Thank goodness it seems to work, it's being built now. . Waiting for the final result to be successful. . .
It took me almost 2 days to search for the cause of this problem. Finally found an effective solution between the lines.

sorry ,I have a new problem. . .build fails again。

end。。。。

keep trying today。

1 try this
“ git clean -fdx”

2 then this
“./gradlew clean  -PchecksumIgnore --info”

it outputs xians BUILD SUCCESSFUL!!!

3 OK,next,try again this.
“./gradlew runGui -PchecksumIgnore --info”

OH,I finally edited and launched jmeter GUI successfully

Well, now just command line gradle can succeed. I don't know if the IDEA import will be successful.

I will try IDEA import。

sorry，IDEA import Still getting the same error。

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'.
```

> Self-suppression not permitted

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'.
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted

now is 2022/3/18 I am come back .

in idea 2021.3.2  import jmeter5.4.3
1 I have Gradle setup in IDEA
[image]

2 Then I found that I can run the command in IDEA here
[image]

[image]

can run successfully。

We can also try the command here
./gradlew build -PchecksumIgnore --info

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking at [gradle-wrapper.properties](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L21) it should be Gradle 6.7
2. Since [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32/) you need [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) to run (and compile) JMeter, lower versions won't work for sure, higher versions might not work
3. I cannot reproduce your issue using the latest stable build of JMeter 5.4.3 from its downloads page:

   [image]

References:

- [Gradle Command-Line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/gradle.md)
- [Building JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html)
- [Build instructions](https://github.com/apache/jmeter#build-instructions)